# What the essence of the instance?

Tags: c#

u can click the button lots of times and every click make a new panel which has different HashCode.But the question is,they all named myPanel and never get wrong.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel myPanel = new Panel();
        Panel myPanel = new Panel();  //Wrong
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel myPanel = new Panel();  //OK
        richTextBox1.AppendText(myPanel.GetHashCode().ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't compile:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();  //Wrong
}
```

Because you've already declared a variable called `myPanel` in this scope (the code between the curly brackets `{ ... }`

Think about it; if you were to say this and it *were* legal syntax:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();  //Wrong
    myPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    myPanel.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

which `myPanel` should be made red and which should be made blue?

This is why variable names need to be unique; so the compiler can be sure which thing you're referring to when you name a variable

This works fine:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();  //OK
    richTextBox1.AppendText(myPanel.GetHashCode().ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

because you only have one variable called `myPanel` in this scope. Scope checking in this sense is a compile-time thing, not a run-time thing. You can repeatedly run code in the click event over and over in runtime and the .net runtime isn't going to complain "you've already run code that uses that variable".

All your variable names in a scope, at compile time, must be unique across all the scopes that apply (one scope can be inside another scope, and variables from the outer scope cannot be repeated inside the inner scope either):

```
void MethodX(){
  int a = 1;

  if(someBoolean){
    int a = 2; //wrong; a is already declared
  }
}
```

Knoop pointed out that method scoped variables can repeat the names of class scoped variables:

```
class Y{

  int a = 1;

  void MethodX(){
    int a = 1; //it's acceptable to repeat the name but..

    a++;      //refers to the A declared in the method
    this.a++; //refers to the A declared in the class
  }
}
```

But really; do yourself a favor and avoid doing this

Comment: A method level scope variable can actually have the same name as a class level scope variable, so I don't entirely agree they always have to be unique.

Comment: @Knoop but then you have to have another way of referring to them so you can indicate which you mean. It's a good point though. I'll add a footnote

Comment: @Caius Jard Thanks a lot ! But how can i find the specific myPanel I new(for example, the thrid click)

Comment: @vincent you either find the specific mypanel you just made by referring to it by name ( like you do when you get its hash code .. or if you mean "how do I get the panel I created first, if this is the third time in clicking the button" - you can't- it's gone out of scope and you didn't keep any reference to it. If you'd added it to eg this.Controls (the collection of all controls on the form) you could find it again but because all you did was get its hash code, basically a bunch of random chars,convert that to a string and add the string to a text box the actual panel is gone,dead and buried

Comment: @Caius Jard  Add the myPanel u have created into the List<Panel>,if u wanna to find it again.Is that the viable way?

Comment: Sure, anything that keeps track of it is acceptable. C# automatically trashes objects in memory of they have no surviving variable references (no way for the code/developer to retrieve them) via a process called garbage collection. Every time you make a variable and assign an object to it, the instance of the object lives in memory somewhere. You can have tens of references to the same thing, all created in different scopes but one by one as they go out of scope and are lost you will eventually have data in memory that has nothing referencing it, and that's when it becomes collectible garbage